# Cannot convert value of type string to expected argument type soundex

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I just wrote this function called `compute` which takes a string and converts it to a soundex value. When I call the function though, it gives me an error that says `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Soundex'`. I am not sure what's going on here, but I think it has something to do with my not declaring the function correctly in the `Soundex` class.

Soundex.swift

```
import Cocoa

class Soundex {

    func compute(word: String) -> String {
        return _compute(word, length: 4)
    }

    func _compute(word: String, length: Int) -> String {
        ...
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
var lastName: String = lastNameText.stringValue
lastName = Soundex.compute(lastName) //get error on this line
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Soundex.compute(lastName)` you are calling a class method. But `compute(_:)` isn't a class method. Change the method to this:

```
class func compute(word: String) -> String {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I changed it to `class func compute`, but now I get the error `Extra argument 'length' in call`. I have added the rest of the function to my original post.

Comment: You can only call class methods from class methods.